# Ubuntu 12.4 running extremely slow

Tags: freeze, bug-reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I just finished installing Ubuntu 12.4 on my PC. However, after the installation, it has been running surprisingly slow. When, I say slow I mean, the launch of applications takes around 2-3 minutes. On top of that, the computer is freezing-up every 5-7 minutes with application UX turning gray.

Here are the specs of my PC. It is a Packard Bell EasyNote.
Intel Core i7-620M Processor
4 GB Memory
NVDIA GeForce GT 320M, 1 GB VRAM
640 GB HDD

Did anyone else have this issue? Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you installed the nvidia drivers?

Comment: Does Disk Utility report any bad sectors for your hard drive?